# C in Go: string ( int ( C.int ) ) returns \u000X

Tags: go

I have an enum in C that I am sharing between projects.

When I use `string ( int ( C.int ) )`

I get \u0002 for third in enum, I just need the number in plain "2"?

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Go `string(int(x))` will produce a string containing the **rune** (aka Unicode point) x; `string(12)` is **not** a shortcut for `fmt.Sprintf("%d", 12)` or `strconv.Itoa`.